# How to capture the return value of an event handler?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to return a variable after a `onclick` function.
I know that this code does not work, but how could I get the variable a that is created inside the function called because of the `onclick`?

```js
myDiv.onclick = function() {
  var a = 20;
  return a
}
console.log(a);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">myDiv</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a DOM event is triggered by the browser, there is no calling code to capture a `return` value in. However, if your goal is to modify the value of the element that triggered the event, just change the element's `textContent` or place the value you want in a higher scoped variable, which can be used later.

```js
// If you want access to the value after the event, 
// declare the variable in a higher scope so you can
// access it when you need to:
let a = null;

myDiv.onclick = function() {
  a = 20;
  
  // Or, if you just want to update the element with a new value
  // just set that value in the element
  this.textContent = a;
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">myDiv</div>
```

Comment: Running your code snippet displays the HTML of the page, not the console... So all we see is `myDiv`

Comment: @OOPSStudio that's the point... You're supposed to click on `myDiv`.

Comment: I see. :) Thank you for explaining that to my small brain.

Answer (score 1):

You want to notify a consumer when your handler has executed:

```js
function log(x) {
  console.log(x);
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
  log(20);
};
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

However that doesn't scale well if you have more than one consumer to notify and possibly introduce unnecessary dependencies. My advice would be to turn an event into a stream into which you push data to consumers:

```js
const {fromEvent} = rxjs;
const {mapTo} = rxjs.operators;

const click$ =
  fromEvent(document.querySelector('button'), 'click')
    .pipe(mapTo(20));

click$.subscribe(x => console.log('subscriber1', x));
click$.subscribe(x => console.log('subscriber2', x));
click$.subscribe(x => console.log('subscriber3', x));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.6/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-r0R52UFUS1Wx7K9DKFCzPkZbmB0xVXJjc/sk9JByGAcHH2VXrj3tKBzmoYp9PgJm8xRVHlfjvDYN4mG7mhnv4w==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to declare a semi-global/global variable and edit its value inside the function. Like so:

```
let theValue;

someElement.onclick = function(){
    theValue = 15;
};

if(typeof theValue !== "undefined"){
    console.log(theValue);
}
```

However I'm not sure if this is a perfect solution for you.

Comment: Your if-statement will always run before the value has changed.

Comment: How so? I have tested this (and I just tested it again) and the if statement is not run. It will only run if `theValue` has been defined....... ?

Comment: The value will never be defined when the if-statement runs, since the if-statement will always run before `theValue = 15` is assigned

Comment: Oh, you mean "be evaluated" not "be run" Now I see what you mean. And yes, of course. This code is not intended to be run directly, but rather it is an example. The if statement is there to prevent the code from printing `undefined`... The only way I could give a working example is if I somehow executed the `onclick` method of an element that doesn't exist. How else do you expect me to post an answer? I can't post working code (it's literally impossible without manually calling `onclick` which would be pointless) so how is pointing out that my code doesn't work "properly" helpful?

Comment: yeah, sorry, I meant evaluated, not run. It seemed like your code was intending to log the value once it was set. But I don't see why the if-statement check is needed, since `theValue` will always be `undefined` before the function has executed, so the problem is more to do with the OP trying to use `a` outside of the function / not correctly understanding asynchronous code.

Comment: I can understand the confusion. I'm glad things are cleared up now.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, it will automatically become a GLOBAL variable.

```js
let myDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv")
let btn = document.getElementById("btn")


myDiv.onclick = function() { a = 20 }
btn.onclick = function() { console.log(a) }
```

```html
<button id="mydiv">1. - click</button>
<button id="btn">2. - cheak var</button>
```

[JavaScript Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_local_global)

Comment: Wow, this is a very interesting code snippet... How does this work? How does `a` make it from one function to another? And how do you declare `a` without a keyword like `var`, `let`, or `const`? I can't wrap my head around what's going on in your post.

Comment: This answer can benefit from an explanation.

Comment: @Rojo Code is pretty self explanatory. Added a link...

Comment: Oh, I see. So this answer is actually the same as 2 other answers here, but it just comes with an extra string attached. Thank you for the explanation, I appreciate it.

Comment: @OOPSStudio Yeah and check the times of the answers.  I seriously don't understand the down-votes. And it is answer to the question. And difference with all other is that my is made in moment of pressing the button.  You all declare it before.

Comment: @ikiK Well technically declaring it before it a benefit, as it keeps code cleaner and reduces the chance of a collision... However I do agree that your post is still helpful and does answer the question.